# подсчитать количество символов в списке (список может сожержать символы строки и цифры)

Tags: lisp

есть такое решение

```
(defun num-atoms (lst)
  (count-if #'atom lst))
```

При вызове

```
(num-atoms '(a 2 bc))
```

считает bc как 1 символ и выдает результат "3", кто может помочь переделать таким образом, чтобы считало bc как два символа и выводило в результат "4"? Если кто знает решение,дайте пояснение что делали,чтобы разобраться в коде